# iOS >> ShareKit: How to Solve the Warnings in the FBRequest File?

Tags: ios, warnings, nsxmlparser, sharekit, fbrequest-form

I'm implementing ShareKit in my App. Everything is working fine, I also got rid of most of the warnings (all the warnings that are caused because ShareKit suports OS 2.x - my app suports 3.2 and above, so I didn't need these code lines anyhow...)

There is only one file I'm not able to solve - the FBRequest.m. I cannot simply remove the lines that get warnings because if I do so my app doesn't connect to Facebook.

In a previous post I published about this issue someone referenced me to a ShareKit fork that supposes to fix this - but (!) it requires that I switch the files that I already modified for my app (and also, I ran the fork "Example App" and found the same warnings...).

If I drill down to the specific Warnings, they sum up to 2 types (I have 9 warnings, but most of them are from the same type)

1. **FBLOG** and **FBLOG2** - whenever one of them appear in the code, I get the following Warning: Unused Entity Issue: Expression result unused
2. **FBXMLHandler** vs. **NSXMLParser** - There are 2 warnings relating to this issue, in the **parseXMLResponse** method:

   ```
   - Class 'FBXMLHandler' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol
   - Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'id<NSXMLParserDelegate>' from incompatible type 'FBXMLHandler *'
   ```

Had anyone happened to solve these issues in their app and can guide me how to deal with them?

OR...

Had anyone encountered these issues, ignored them, uploaded their app to app store and was not rejected by Apple App Review (and therefore can say "hi, you can just ignore these warnings. Apple don't care...")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one post that solves the **FBXMLHandler vs. NSXMLParser** issues

here is the link:

https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/215

Regarding the **FBLOG** issue - I just did "**//**" for all the lines that produce this warning and it seems to be working fine.

If anyone knows that what I had done here is wrong and may cause other problems, do tell...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and I ended up doing just what you did :))

The warning appears because of the parentheses. It interprets the function as an expression and considers that you didn't use it's result.

Regarding what it does, I'm not 100% sure but looking at it I'm quite convinced it's just a log function useful for debug without any actual role.